# Weird backslash behavior with Laravel's Blueprint's default function

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, default-value, backslash

I'm trying to add a default value to a column in MySQL through Laravel's migration system. The following:

```
$table->string(...)->default('App\User')->change(); // OR
$table->string(...)->default('App\\User')->change();
```

produces a default value of `AppUser` instead of `App\User`. If I do this:

```
$table->string(...)->default('App\\\User')->change();
```

then it produces a default value of `App\\User`. I tried leveraging the use of `DB::raw()` inside `default()` as well but got the same results.

Any idea what it might be happening? I couldn't find any documentation on the `default()` function anywhere.

Comment: Saw something interesting here: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/136

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I actually found that, thanks. It seems the `default()` function is handled by the `__call()` magic method so I've been trying to dig through the framework's code and see what I find.

Comment: What are your Laravel and MySQL versions? `->default('App\\\User')` works for me.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Laravel is 5.4 not sure about MySQL. That works for me too but it makes it `App\\User` instead of `App\User`.

Comment: `->default('App\\\User')` results in `App\User` on my machine (Laravel 5.6 and MySQL 5.7).